# Group Count in T/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Source:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTab (Value INT, Value1 varchar(10), Value2 varchar(10), 
GRP varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #TempTab
SELECT 1,'One','One','One'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'One','One','One'
UNION ALL
sELECT 1,'One','One','Two'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'One','One','One'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'One','One','Two'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'One','One','Three'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'One','One','One'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'One','One','One'
```

Current query effort:

```
SELECT Value, Value1, Value2, GRP
, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY Value, Value1, Value2) CNT 
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Value, Value1, Value2, GRP ORDER BY Value) RN
, CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Value, Value1, Value2, GRP) > 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END IsMultiple
FROM #TempTab


DROP TABLE #TempTab
```

Current output:

```
Value   Value1  Value2  GRP     CNT RN  IsMultiple
1       One     One     One     3   1   1
1       One     One     One     3   2   1
1       One     One     Two     3   1   0
2       One     One     One     3   1   0
2       One     One     Two     3   1   0
2       One     One     Three   3   1   0
3       One     One     One     2   1   1
3       One     One     One     2   2   1
```

Desired output:

```
Value   Value1  Value2  GRP     CNT RN  IsMultiple  NoUniqueGRPed
1       One     One     One     3   1   1           2
1       One     One     One     3   2   1           2
1       One     One     Two     3   1   0           2
2       One     One     One     3   1   0           3
2       One     One     Two     3   1   0           3
2       One     One     Three   3   1   0           3
3       One     One     One     2   1   1           1
3       One     One     One     2   2   1           1
```

Goal:

I am trying to derive a field called NoUniqueGRPed. This field is
 basically count of unique grouped records based on Value, Value1, and
 Value2 fields. i.e. Value = 1, Value1 = One, and Value2 = One has
 three records but two unique GRP values (One and Two) so NoUniqueGRPed
 should be 2.

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to do the unique
 aggregation/grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try qith `cross apply`:

```
SELECT ...,
       ca.NoUniqueGRPed
FROM #TempTab t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT GRP) AS NoUniqueGRPed 
            FROM #TempTab t2 
            WHERE t1.Value = t2.Value)ca
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly with window functions:

```
select tt.*,
       count(distinct grp) over (partition by value, value1, value2) as NewColumn
from #TempTab tt
```

EDIT:

I though that limitation had been fixed.  Alas.  You can do this using a combination of `sum()` and `row_number()`:

```
select tt.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by value, value1, value2) as NewColumn
from (select tt.*, row_number() over (partition by value, value1, value2, grp order by grp) as seqnum
      from #TempTab tt
     ) tt
```

Comment: as I remember you can not count distinct with window function.

Comment: "Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause." Getting this error. :(